# Solr comma separated field - facet search

Tags: solr, lucene

I got a field in my solr index which holds comma separated values like "area1,area2,area3,area4". There are documents in it where the value is just one value like "area6".

Now i want to make a facet search over all this values.

**Example (This is what i want):**

area1:10

area2:4297

area3:54

area4:65

area6:87

**This is what i get**

area1,area2,area3,area4: 7462

area6: 87

Does solr delivers any solutions for this problem or must i seperate the different values on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While indexing you need to get tokens out of the data using `,`. You can use the `PatternTokenizerFactory` tokenizer with `,` as the `pattern`. This would split your text whenever it finds a `,`.

The field in your `schema.xml` should be `multivalued`.